# Display_rows() and column_cb() strange behaviour

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization, hooks, wp-list-table

I found a strange behavior of my functions.

I thought to pass the id from `display_rows()` to `column_cb()`, but the problem is that the program passes only the first digit. Any hint?

`column_cb()`:

```
function column_cb($item) {
    return sprintf('<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="%s" />', $item['id']);
}
```

`display_rows()`:

```
function display_rows() {
    $records = $this->items;
    list( $columns, $hidden ) = $this->get_column_info();

    if(!empty($records)){
        foreach($records as $rec) {
            echo '<tr id="record_'.$rec->id.'">';
            foreach ( $columns as $column_name => $column_display_name ) {
                $class = "class='$column_name column-$column_name'";
                $style = "";
                if ( in_array( $column_name, $hidden ) ) $style = 'style="display:none;"';
                    $attributes = $class . $style;
                    $editlink  = '/wp-admin/link.php?action=edit&id='.(int)$rec->id;

                    //Display the cell
                    switch ( $column_name ) {
                        case "cb":  echo '<th scope="row" class="check-column">'.$this->column_cb(stripslashes($rec->id)).'</th>'; break;
                        case "col_name":    echo '<td '.$attributes.'><strong>'.$this->column_title(stripslashes($rec->product_name_name)).'</strong></td>'; break;
                    }
             }
                    echo'</tr>';
        }
     }
 }
```

The same problem happens if I try to pass the value name to `column_title()`.

`column_title()`:

```
function column_title($item){
    $actions = array(
                     'edit'      => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&product=%s">Edit</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'edit',$item['ID']),
                     'delete'    => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&product=%s">Delete</a>',$_REQUEST['page'],'delete',$item['ID']),
        );

       //Return the title contents
       return sprintf('<a href="#"><b>%1$s</b></a> %3$s',
            /*$1%s*/ $item['product_name'],
            /*$2%s*/ $item['id'],
            /*$3%s*/ $this->row_actions($actions)
        );
    }
```

Comment: If you dump the passed `$item` does it contain expected data?

Comment: Nope, it prints: `string(1) "1"`instead of `string(1) "15"`. In fact the program works great with numbers from 1 to 9, and it has problem with number with 2 or N digits. But I do not understand why.
If I print `$rec->id` in the `display_rows()` it prints for example 15, in the `column_cb()` or `column_title()` it prints 1.

Comment: If I write everything in `display_rows()` like this: `case "cb":    echo '<th scope="row" class="check-column"><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="'.stripslashes($rec->id).'" /></th>';   break;` everything seems working, but I need to use the other functions! Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$item['id']` I have to write `$item`. Fixed!

Comment: Just a suggestion, whenever you develop a theme/plugin, set your debug to true in wp-config.php. Most problems are easily solved by just doing this one simple thing, as all problems in code is printed to screen